# Regexp OR operator

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess to generate nice looking links, and i need to include `or` on slash

so that for example
`domain.com/page/12/a/`
 and
`domain.com/page/12/a` will work

What I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/?)([^/]*) index.php?do=atoz&category=$1&letter=$2&type=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your case the simple quantifier `?` for *zero or one* should work.

```
^page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?
                      ##         #
```

Edit: You also might look for a non-matching group so that you can quantify it as optional. It starts with `?:`.

Comment: In the examples given in your question, it is also at the end.

Comment: because third variable is optional

Comment: you probably mean the last part optional. I added that.

Comment: which third variable? your question has only two. perhaps your question does not work? And please read my answer exemplary, it is only suggesting how it *could* work not what you must use. There is more than one way so solve this btw., however it seems like that I have understanding problems of your question and less a problem with formulating a regular expression :)

Comment: I edited once again as it seems you're looking to have the third parameter optional (maybe)? I dunno how apache will deal with optional match groups, so perhaps this doesn't work with apache, per PCRE (which is used by apache) this should work.